# How to make a drop down read only inside a grid view after binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using grid view which contains a drop down list inside it along with other controls.
I am sucessfully binding the data selected from database.
but, i want to know is there any way to make this drop down as read only..
Please help..and ReadOnly="True" is not working

Comment: readonly dropdown? did you mean disabled, in which you cannot change the selectedIndex?

Comment: Can u post your code ?And i hope `readonly` means you want to show selected index .

Comment: I am binding the drop down , with the value fetched from the database, so i do not want the user to get an impression that it can be changed/modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {

        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

        DropdownList ddlxxx= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlName");               
         //This will make your ddl readonly 
         ddlxxx.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```